# What's the difference between frames per second and updates per second?

Tags: terminology

FPS is obviously just the number of frame changes per second, but I have no idea what UPS is and Google is returning nothing.

ps, this is a tutorial question, so I'm not just making up UPS :P

Comment: If you're doing game dev, you should be asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updates per second could be how often the game world is updated, ie positions of the game objects, colisions etc. as opposed to how often the scene is rendered (FPS).

Comment: In general, how often the game world is updates is in frames per second, one state of the game being one frame.

Comment: @Alex, thanks this is probably what it means in the context of what we're doing :)

Comment: What is with the downvote? Someone's just being nasty, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Arda Xi I'm not a game dev but I believe it's generally better to have a fixed rate for your gamestate that's independent of the renderer. Theres some pros and cons on [this question here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step)

Comment: @AlexJ.Roberts If that's the case here, then the question belongs on Game Dev.

Comment: Yeah fair enough

Comment: Multiplayer games are probably the best way to tell the difference, No matter how many Frames you are getting on your computer, The servers are the ones actually moving the game forward. If your game freezes, you get 0 FPS, but when you return, things have changed, because it was still updating and accepting commands from other players.

Answer (score 7):

If you're referring to multiplayer games, "updates per second" is also known as the "tick rate" of the server, which determines how often it recalculates the game's state.

> The server simulates the game in discrete time steps called ticks. [...] During each tick, the server processes incoming user commands, runs a physical simulation step, checks the game rules, and updates all object states. After simulating a tick, the server decides if any client needs a world update and takes a snapshot of the current world state if necessary. A higher tickrate increases the simulation precision, but also requires more CPU power and available bandwidth on both server and client.
>
> — ["Source Multiplayer Networking", Valve Developer Community Wiki](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking)

Even beyond multiplayer games, there is likely a discrepancy between the actual simulation and visual rendering.

Comment: It's important to note that newer Source multiplayer games run the server at a fixed tick rate of 67.  This applies to Team Fortress 2 and Counter-Strike: Source.